# R^2 coefficient remains high with very high test_size

Tags: python, linear-regression, cross-validation

I'm trying to train-test a multiple regression model in python. I've tried varying the test_size parameter in `cross_validation.train_test_split(X, y, test_size)`to test the accuracy of the model. But even a very high value of test_size=0.9 gives a R^2 coefficient of 0.97. I'm unable to understand this at a conceptual level. Can someone please give me some insight into this problem?

Here is my code:

```
import quandl
df = quandl.get('WIKI/GOOGL')

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import math
from sklearn import preprocessing, cross_validation, svm
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

#Create feature dataframe from input data
df1 = df[['Adj. Open','Adj. High','Adj. Low','Adj. Close','Adj. Volume']].copy()
df1['HL_PCT'] = ((df1['Adj. High']-df1['Adj. Low'])/df1['Adj. Low']) * 100.
df1['PCT_change'] = ((df1['Adj. Close']-df1['Adj. Open'])/df1['Adj. Open']) * 100.
df1 = df1[['Adj. Close', 'HL_PCT', 'PCT_change', 'Adj. Volume']]
forecast_col = 'Adj. Close'
df1.fillna(-99999, inplace=True)

#Offset for y label data
forecast_out = int(math.ceil(0.01 * len(df1)))

#Offset 'label' by forecast_out days
df1['label'] = df1[forecast_col].shift(-forecast_out)
df1.dropna(inplace=True)

#Create feature matrix, label vector
X = np.array(df1.drop(['label'], 1))
X = preprocessing.scale(X)
y = np.array(df1['label'])

#Split dataset into train, test sets
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = cross_validation.train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.9)

#Perform linear regression, cross-validation by varying test_size: 0.2 to 0.95
clf = LinearRegression()
clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
accuracy = clf.score(X_test, y_test)
print accuracy
```

Comment: Without the actual data its very hard to say. And one more thing, R2 score is not accuracy.

Comment: If you run the script, the data will be imported from quandl: `df = quandl.get('WIKI/GOOGL')` Thanks for the correction about R2. My primary question is that R2 doesn't degrade much for the test data even if I use only 10% of the dataset to train my model. I'm hoping someone can run the code by varying the `test_size` parameter and let me know why is that the case.